# why make timer callbacks static?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Most of the winforms timer examples I have looked at declare static callbacks.

Is that irrelevant to the functionality of timers?

I removed the "static" modifier and things seem to be moving along just fine ...

Comment: You probably looked in very specific examples. Most examples I've seen use ordinary class members as callback methods, e.g. [this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2008/10/27/properly-handling-a-winforms-timer-event.aspx) (one of the top Google results)

Comment: In the past I used a framework that got very weird about updating UI elements. Nokia has apparently decided to solve this problem by laying off developers. Can't say I miss C++ much ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's irrelevant - the methods are just used to create delegates, really. If the callbacks need to use any state from the instance (e.g. to update a particular UI element), make them instance methods. If they don't, it's fine for them to be static. The timer won't care either way.